# BASH: grep with g=db_$((e ))

Tags: database, bash, awk, grep

i am still writing a bash script and need your help !

I want to grep with two parameters, but it doesn't work.

This script stands in an until queue so it runs x times.

Please help me:

```
e=1
g=db_$((e++))


for call in $(cat /home/palyground/foo.xml |grep $HOME|grep db_$g| awk -F \" '{print $2}')
do
:
done

echo $call
```

My Problem is, that the $g is still standing by 1 and dont move to 2 3 eg.

I want to grep |grep db_1 in the first time in the second time |grep db_2 e.g.

Do you have any soulutions for this Problem ?

Comment: Your whole pipeline can be replaced with `awk -F\" -v h="$HOME" g="db_$g" '$0 ~ h && $0 ~ g {print $2}' /home/playground/foo.xml`. It's almost never necessary to pipe the output of `grep` into `awk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i get the right code now..

First time thank you very much Jotne and chepner !

The right code:

```
f=1
q=/home/playground/foo.xml
g=db_$((f++))

HOME_GREP=${DB_HOME}/${g}
var1=$(cat  $q | grep ${HOME_GREP} )
var2=$(echo $var1|  awk -F \" '{print $2}' )
echo $var2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
g=$((++e))
for call in $(awk -F \" '$0~home && $0~db {print $2}' home="$HOME" db="db_$g" /home/palyground/foo.xml)
```

By changing to `++e` it will starts with `1` instead of `0`

Comment: I do not see that `g=db_$((e++))` is inside any loop, hence it will never be run more than once.  You need an outer loop.

Comment: So `g=` is inside this until loop?  I would help if you post the whole script.

Comment: I have the answer i post it tomorrow i haven't enough points to post it now. 
for the first time code without good arrangement.
  f=1
    q=/home/playground/foo.xml
    g=db_$((f++))
    
    HOME_GREP=${DB_HOME}/${g}
    var1=$(cat  $q | grep ${HOME_GREP} )
    var2=$(echo $var1|  awk -F \" '{print $2}' )
    echo $var2

Comment: Thanks to you an chepner